# In azure Logic Apps do we have to create separate logic app for each integration

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In Azure Logic Apps do we have to create the separate logic app for each integration, if we create separate then how cost is applied?

In azure Logic Apps the how price calculated is somewhat confusing.

I asked the above question as I don't know whether it'll charge for storage of each logic apps.

Please if possible Provide explanation for pricing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Azure Logic Apps do we have to create the separate logic app for each integration, if we create separate then how cost is applied?

You don't have to create the separate logic app for each integration account, but you can just use only one account and you can change it (integration account must be the same region as the logic app).

If you create separate logic app, they will cost by **Data Retention** as **$0.12 Per GB/month**.

> Please if possible Provide explanation for pricing

You could refer to the [pricing details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/logic-apps/) and use the [**Pricing calculator of Logic App**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/), it will be helpful.

Comment: I am not using integration account as for creating integration account extra pricing is there. For logic app pricing is done only when it is triggered right??

Comment: @vikram I think you should also pay for Data Rentention which I have mentioned，because azure will store the data  of the existing app.

Answer (score 2):

In Azure logic apps, pricing is calculated based on the total number of executions, connectors used and data retention. Values of all the logic apps under an Azure Subscription will be considered for calculating the cost. Azure Integration account is for maintaining the availability and security for the resources mapped to it.

Logic apps can be created and used with out Integration Accounts. Integration Accounts are suggested for large scale enterprise business integrations.

As pricing is calculated based on the consolidated usage, any number of logic apps can be created. Only the Logic App executions decides the cost.